# Need Help in creating a calculated column or Measure for a Flag Column in power bi

Tags: powerbi, dax

I need help in Creating a Flag column based on the aggregated values of two columns in power bi, similar to group by in sql and Fixed{Columnname:Value} in tableau.

Amount_rc, Amount_rb are two numeric columns

Flag Condition:

```
Flag = 
IF(
    'Table'[rc]<>0 && 'Table'[rb]<>0,
    "rc nd rb",
    IF(
        'Table'[rc]<>0 && 'Table'[rb]=0,
        "rc not rb",
        "rb not rc"
    ) 
)
```

The above calculation is working at each record level. I want it to work at summarized level as below

[image]

Comment: Can you show your SQL query?

Answer (score 0):

Make a measure (not a calculated column) and wrap the columns with a [`SUM`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/sum-function-dax) or [`MAX`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/max-function-dax) aggregate:

```
Flag = IF(SUM('Table'[rc])<>0 && SUM('Table'[rb])<>0,
    "rc nd rb",
    IF(SUM('Table'[rc])<>0 && SUM('Table'[rb])=0,
        "rc not rb",
        "rb not rc"))
```

(probably `rc` column should be `rv`, considering your screenshot)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need 3 separate **Measure** to achieve your required output.

**Measure-1**

```
rc_new = SUM('Table'[rc])
```

**Measure-2**

```
rb_new = SUM('Table'[rb])
```

**Measure-3**

```
Flag = 
IF(
    rc_new <> 0 && rb_new <> 0,
    "rc nd rb",
    IF(
        rc_new <> 0 && rb_new = 0,
        "rc not rb",
        "rb not rc"
    ) 
)
```

Now add them to the table visual instead of adding rc and rb column directly.

Comment: Hello,

Thanks for your help. I forgot to mention that i need to use matrix visual as part of req. to show hierarchy and drill down also matrix has the view data as table option which is imp.. Now the matrix visual is not allowing to keep this Flag measure on the rows. So that the reason i was looking at calculated column but it is computing at each record level

Thanks!

Comment: Then I suggest you do everything in data transformation layer. Copy your base table, then apply group by as per your requirement and finally create the flag column. This will sove your issue.